# I don't know why labels of pie chart are written twice

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations, label

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import font_manager, rc
import seaborn as sns
    
frequency = [35.3, 4.1, 6.9, 1.7, 0.3, 13.4, 7.2, 4.0, 6.5, 13.5, 7.0]
    
font_path = "C:\Windows\Fonts\malgun.ttf"
font = font_manager.FontProperties(fname = font_path).get_name()
rc('font', family = font)
    
places = list(df['비고'])
times = list(df[df.columns[0]])
    
colors = sns.color_palette('hls', len(places))
    
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig1.set_facecolor('white')
ax1.pie(frequency, labels = places, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=90, counterclock=False, colors= colors)
ax1.axis('equal')
ax1.set_facecolor('white')
    
frequency = [35.3, 4.1, 6.9, 1.7, 0.3, 13.4, 7.2, 4.0, 6.5, 13.5, 7.0]
    
sum_pct = 0
threshold = 5
    
total = np.sum(frequency)
    
bbox_props = dict(boxstyle='square',fc='w',ec='w',alpha=0) 
    
config = dict(arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-'),bbox=bbox_props,va='center')
     
for i,l in enumerate(places):
    ang1, ang2 = ax1.patches[i].theta1, ax1.patches[i].theta2 
    center, r = ax1.patches[i].center, ax1.patches[i].r 
        
    if i < len(places) - 1:
        sum_pct += float(f'{frequency[i]/total*100:.2f}')
        text = f'{frequency[i]/total*100:.2f}%'
    else: 
        text = f'{100-sum_pct:.2f}%'
        
        
    if frequency[i]/total*100 < threshold:
        ang = (ang1+ang2)/2 
        x = np.cos(np.deg2rad(ang)) 
        y = np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang)) 
            

        horizontalalignment = {-1: "right", 1: "left"}[int(np.sign(x))]
        connectionstyle = "angle,angleA=0,angleB={}".format(ang) 
        config["arrowprops"].update({"connectionstyle": connectionstyle})
        ax1.annotate(text, xy=(x, y), xytext=(1.5*x, 1.2*y),
                    horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment, **config)
    else:
            x = (r/2)*np.cos(np.pi/180*((ang1+ang2)/2)) + center[0]
            y = (r/2)*np.sin(np.pi/180*((ang1+ang2)/2)) + center[1]
            ax1.text(x,y,text,ha='center',va='center',fontsize=12)
```

I am using annotation to see pie chart comfortable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mY21Y.png)

Like what you see, labels of pie chart are written twice

but, i don't know how to solov this problem

see my code and please tell me what is wrong

if you want more explation, please comment under

Answer (score 0):

You specifically ask [`pie`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html) to plot the percentages for you with `autopct='%1.1f%%'`:

```
ax1.pie(frequency, labels=places,
        autopct='%1.1f%%',                                # HERE
        startangle=90, counterclock=False, colors= colors)
```